# Add / Remove Elements Dynamically

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Now i done the ADD /Remove Elements

How to add/remove elements dynamically, pease find the image attachment, which shows the better understand, [image]

category which populate records from database category table, and when user select the particular category than sub category will populate from datbase sub category table,

am looking one jquery or some open which do this same work,

refer some good plugins,

How to add the element when i click the ADD Elment, please chekc my code below

```
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
var hdn_add_element_cnt = $("#hdn_add_element_cnt").val();
        hdn_add_element_cnt = parseInt(hdn_add_element_cnt);
        var app_str = "<div id=element_"+hdn_add_element_cnt+">New Element  "+hdn_add_element_cnt+" <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"delete_element("+hdn_add_element_cnt+")\">Delete</a></div>";
        $('#element_area').append(app_str);

    $("#add_element").click(function(){
        var hdn_add_element_cnt = $("#hdn_add_element_cnt").val();
        hdn_add_element_cnt = parseInt(hdn_add_element_cnt);
        hdn_add_element_cnt = hdn_add_element_cnt+1;
        var app_str = "<div id=element_"+hdn_add_element_cnt+">New Element  "+hdn_add_element_cnt+" <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"delete_element("+hdn_add_element_cnt+")\">Delete</a></div>";
        $('#element_area').fadeIn(10000).append(app_str);
        //Increment Elemenet ID Count +1

        document.getElementById("hdn_add_element_cnt").value = hdn_add_element_cnt;

    })
})

function delete_element(element_id_no){
    var get_element_hidden_cnt = $("#hdn_add_element_cnt").val();
    $("#element_"+element_id_no).fadeOut(100).remove();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:#FF0000;">
    <div id="add_element" style="width:400px; height:75px;">
        ADD Element
    </div>
    <div id="element_area">

    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hdn_add_element_cnt" value="1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you add more details as to what you'd like to do with the table?

Comment: What doesn't work? It'd be nice to know...

Comment: now i just updated working one, just sharing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't need plugins to do this. Standard functions work well:

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds elements, so to add a `<div>` to the `<body>`, just do this:

```
$('body').append('<div id="foobar">This is my text</div>');
```

---

[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) similarly removes elements, so to remove that `<div>` that you added, just do this:

```
$('#foobar').remove();
```

---

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) can be used to set the contents of an element. `.text()` is usually for setting the displayed text, and `.html()` is for adding content elements:

```
$('#foobar').text('Hello');
$('#foobar').html('<h1 class="foo">Hello</h1>');
```

---

Your question is *really* vague, so I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: what about dynamic elements population

Comment: Don't ever do this: `$('div#foobar').remove();`  It makes your query exceptionally slow in comparison to just `$('#foobar').remove();`.

Comment: can i remove the element using $('<div id="foobar">This is my text</div>').remove();