# How to create dynamic control in MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, webforms

I created a registration form for employee. In that form I have a field called skills.

If the employee click "Add another skill" button a new set of skill text box should be created.

Likewise the number of skill text box should be created dynamically based upon the number of button click.

Whether it can be achieved in asp.net MVC4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add / Remove Elements Dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584202/add-remove-elements-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery selector to select the element that you want to add and append to the parent element.

some samples:

http://coursesweb.net/jquery/add-remove-elements-content-jquery

[Add / Remove Elements Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584202/add-remove-elements-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="#" id="new-skill"> Add another skill </a>
```

**Script File**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#new-skill").on("click", function(ev) {
             ev.preventDefault();
             $("#idOfYourForm").append("<input type='text' name='skill' />");
        });
    });
</script>
```